# Как изменить механизм появления блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно изменить механизм появления блока. Сейчас блок `.panel` появляется когда блок `.header` весь заходит наверх в невидимую область, а блок `.content` становится видимым полностью. А прячется блок `.panel` когда с нижней части экрана только появляется верхний край блока `.footer`. А вот как сделать так, чтобы блок `.panel` появлялся тогда, когда блок `.content` достигал центра экрана по вертикали, а прятался когда блок `.footer` достигал также центра экрана? При этом все блоки могут быть разной высоты, а блоки `.header` и `.footer` называться иначе. Спасибо!

```js
$(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            var element = $('.content');
            var distanceTop = element.offset().top;
            var distanceHeight = element.offset().top - ($(window).height() - element.height())
            if (windowScroll > distanceTop && windowScroll < distanceHeight)
                $('.panel').animate({'left':'50px'},500);
            else
                $('.panel').stop(true).animate({'left':'-50px'},200);
        });
    });
```

```css
.header {
height: 1000px;
background: green;
}
.footer {
height: 1000px;
background: blue;
}
.content {
height: 3000px;
}
.panel {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: chocolate;
position: fixed;
top: 45%;
left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var element = $('.content');
    var distanceTop = element.offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2); // вычитаем половину высоты экрана
    var distanceHeight = element.offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2 - element.height()); // вычитаем половину высоты экрана вместо целой высоты экрана
    if (windowScroll > distanceTop && windowScroll < distanceHeight)
      $('.panel').animate({
        'left': '50px'
      }, 500);
    else
      $('.panel').stop(true).animate({
        'left': '-50px'
      }, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  height: 3000px;
}

.panel {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: chocolate;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
```